# Objective-C: Converting NSData to an int or char

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion, nsdata

```
NSData * data;
NSFileHandle * file;

file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath: @"script.txt"]; //this is wrong, as I have to provide a full pathname, but disregard for now

[file seekToFileOffset: i]; //i not mentioned here, as this is only a snippet of code. Suffice to know that in the file it falls at the beginning of an integer I want to read

data = [file readDataOfLength: 5]; //5-digit integer that I want to read
```

Now how do I go about casting data as an int which I can use (i.e. for performing arithmetic operations)?

Comment: Does script.txt contain a plain text (i.e. ASCII) representation of the integer, as one might assume from it's name and file extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are reading your integer from a text file, you can convert it like this:

```
char buf[6];
[data getBytes:buf length:5];
buf[5] = '\0';
NSInteger res = atoi(buf);
```

This assumes an encoding that uses one byte per character, which is consistent with the call of `[file readDataOfLength: 5]` in the code snippet that you provided.

If the number of digits is not known ahead of time, you can do this:

```
char buf[11]; // Max 10 digits in a 32-bit number + 1 for null terminator
bzero(buf, 11);
[data getBytes:buf length:variableLength];
NSInteger res = atoi(buf);
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. The file is ASCII encoded, so it is one byte per character indeed.

Comment: Just a quick follow-up question:
Suppose the number of bytes I read is not a constant (i.e. like 5 in that case) but a variable. Then, this approach would likely not work as I can't declare an array with a non-constant number of elements. What are my options then?

Comment: @Alexander You can declare an array of the max length for an int (10 digits + 1 for a terminating zero), fill it with zeros, and then call `getBytes:length:`. Take a look at the edit.

Comment: Thanks again.
Finally, suppose the bytes represent a float, and not an int. I suppose I would then have to use `atof` instead of `atoi`?

Comment: @Alexander Yes, this is correct. You may also need to allocate more bytes to the `buf`, because a float could use more digits than an `int`.

Comment: One more thing: 
When we fill the array with zeroes, wouldn't that give us an incorrect number when we're converting to int?
Let's say we read the number 1234. 
getBytes would then convert it to {'1','2','3','4','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'}
and atoi would convert it to 12340000000, which is not exactly what we want?

Comment: @Alexander No, the array would contain "real" zeros, not zero characters `'0'`, as in `{'1', '2', '3', '4', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'}` (note the slashes). It's like having lots of null terminators (of course, `atoi` or `atof` is going to take the first one, and then stop).

Answer (score 2):

A way of doing this would be to convert the data to an NSString then get the integer value from that:

```
// assuming UTF-8 encoding
NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
int val = [temp intValue];
```

Docs for reference:
[NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Comment: And if I want to get a char value from the NSString?

Comment: `– characterAtIndex:` will return a `unichar` at the given index

Answer (score 2):

A little more generally, you can use this for currency or scientific notation, etc. or for an int or floating point as coded here...

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSNumberFormatter * format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[format setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [format numberFromString:string];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this, assuming script.txt contains plain text, I'd use [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:scriptPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (!fileString) { // Handle error }
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:fileString];
[scanner setScanLocation:i];
int value = 0;
if (![scanner scanInt:&value]) { // Unable to scan integer from string }

// value should contain your integer here
```

Answer (score 0):

NSData *dData ;

const char*  fData =[dData bytes];